Как добавить все эндпойнты (paths) из разных файлов Swagger в один?
Есть Swagger файл (OpenAPIv3.1.0) index.yaml. В нём написано стандартно:
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Your API Title
  description: Single-line or multiline description of the API.
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: "https://App"
paths:

Есть куча других yaml файлов, в которых все эндпойнты описаны. Например в users.yaml описаны /users (get/post), /users/{userId} (get/patch/delete) и другие пути. В файле settings описаны эндпойнты для настроек. И так далее.
Как все эти эндопойнты из разных файлов вставить в один единственный?
Вариант, который пробовал и не помогает:
paths:
  $ref: './users.yaml'
  $ref: './settings.yaml'
  $ref: './auth.yaml'

